# missing method exception can't find pinvoke dll

Tags: c#, c++, dll, compact-framework

I will give you a brief description of my software before I ask questions.

So there is a front end C# code which provides the user interface and a back end C++ code that deals with the hardware.

The C# project creates an executable (.exe) file and the C++ project creates a DLL which talk with each other using pinvoke calls (import/export functions).  All this worked fine on WEC7.

Now, we are moving to WEC2013 with Toradex. I downloaded the WEC2013 SDK from Toradex’s website and was able to port my code and build it on VS2013.

*I copied all the required files on a USB and when I tried running it the C# exe is not able to communicate with the C++ Dll. The error I get is :
missingmethodexception can't find pinvoke dll “xyz.dll”*

I have made sure the dll exists at the specified location. The dll also has the required export functions.

First I thought the function parameters in the export functions could be an issue, but I tried calling function which requires no parameter with the same result.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: The usual problem is that you forgot to copy a DLL that xyz.dll needs.  The next usual problem is that it is a DLL that you didn't previously need.  Like msvcr120.dll, the VS2013 specific C runtime dll.  Use Process Monitor to get insight.

Comment: Hi Hans, thank you so much for the reply. I tried the dumpbin /dependents xyz.dll and this is what it listed:   coredll.dll, msvcp110d.dll, ws2.dll, mmtimer.dll, ole32.dll, oleaut32.dll and msvcr110d.dll. Most of these are part of the SDK that I downloaded from Toradex. I even manually copied  msvcp110d.dll and msvcr110d.dll to the same directory as xyz.dll but the problem still exists. I am not sure how to use process monitor on wec2013. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: Deploying the Debug build of your project is never a good idea.  Pretty hard to guess where you got msvcr110d.dll from, you can't just copy the one you found on your own machine.  Call the vendor to ask for support.

Comment: Can not find DLL means that the exe either can not find the DLL (where did you save it, do you use a path in your DLLImport?). Or the DLL can not be loaded for missing other dependencies or the function can not be found in the DLL (name mangled) or the DLL is for a different platform (x86 or Arm or???). If a DLL named xyz is already loaded and another DLL with the same name is referenced, the newer DLL is not loaded but the old one will be used (DLL hell)! I would start with a simple C app that loads the DLL using LoadLibary and then tries to use one exported function with GetProcAddress().

Comment: Thank you everyone for the responses. The problem was (as Hans mentioned) the xyz dll required the msvcr120.dll, the VS2013 specific C runtime dll. Once I placed this at the right location everything worked fine. I am surprised this C runtime Dll is not a part of the OS. Thanks again for all the help.